# Android Studio ML kit cannot load OCR module

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services, firebase-mlkit

I am working on an android app that involves ML kit. I went through the [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) on how to set up Android Studio to work with Firebase. Then I headed to use the text recognition API. Here is the code that I am having in some button click listener:

```java
        FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
            .getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();
        Task<FirebaseVisionText> result = detector.processImage(
            FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test))
        )
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
                    System.out.println(firebaseVisionText);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

I get the following logs:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ocr not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ocr:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ocr:0
D/TextNativeHandle: Cannot load feature, fall back to load dynamite module.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr:0
E/Vision: Error loading module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr optional module true: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
D/TextNativeHandle: Broadcasting download intent for dependency ocr
W/TextNativeHandle: Native handle not yet available. Reverting to no-op handle.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ocr not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ocr:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ocr:0
D/TextNativeHandle: Cannot load feature, fall back to load dynamite module.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr:0
E/Vision: Error loading module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr optional module true: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/System.err: com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException: Waiting for the text recognition model to be downloaded. Please wait.
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzrw.zzd(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@@24.0.0:21)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzrw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@@24.0.0:39)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpd.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.0.0:31)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpf.call(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzoz.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.0.0:32)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzoy.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zze.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.0.0:6)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

I googled around to see how I can fix any of those errors:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ocr not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ocr:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ocr:0
D/TextNativeHandle: Cannot load feature, fall back to load dynamite module.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr:0
E/Vision: Error loading module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr optional module true: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

```
W/System.err: com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException: Waiting for the text recognition model to be downloaded. Please wait.
```

So far I have tried clearing Google Play Services data (version `19.4.20`), restarting/recreating the emulator, tweaking Gradle configurations (e.g. adding/removing `firebase-core` dependency).
Project-level config:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App-module-level config:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.app"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I decided to give Barcode API a shot, and added

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.0.1'
```

as dependency. To my surprise, when I made an API call to it, the success listner was hit and the following logs appeared:

```
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.firebase.ml.vision.dynamite.barcode:10000 and remote module com.google.firebase.ml.vision.dynamite.barcode:0
    Selected local version of com.google.firebase.ml.vision.dynamite.barcode
W/is.moneytravel: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
I/tflite: Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
I/native: barcode_detector_client.cc:222 Not using NNAPI
```

While the OCR API still produced the same error.
I think it has to deal with the repositories the libraries are fetched from.
Barcode API:

```
Considering local module com.google.firebase.ml.vision.dynamite.barcode:10000 and remote module com.google.firebase.ml.vision.dynamite.barcode:0
```

OCR API:

```
Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ocr:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ocr:0
```

I have too little experience with Gradle and Firebase to figure this one out.
Why is OCR API fetched from `android.gms`, while Barcode API comes from `firebase.ml`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to update Google Play Services app. I did not consider this as an option at first as I would have expected an API 29 emulator to have an up-to-date Google Play Services installed. I signed into Google Play on the emulator, searched Google Play Services, uninstalled it (there was no "update" option), and installed it again. It still says that the installed version is `19.4.20` though the text recognition started working as expected. Here are some relevant logs:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ocr not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ocr:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ocr:0
D/TextNativeHandle: Cannot load feature, fall back to load dynamite module.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr:1
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr, version >= 1
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
```

Comment: We cannot expect our users to update their google play services for our app to work. How can we package up what is needed in the app itself for a production release?

Comment: I'm having google play service of 20+ but still face this issue. Maybe something else solved it.

Comment: Did you explicitly update google play services? @Arshed

Comment: In some device firebase ML kit not installing. I made him wait for 10 min but still can't installed text recognition model .Do you have any solution ?

Comment: @bdevloper have you tried installing any other models? I had issues only with OCR, other models were loading fine.

Comment: I use a OnePlus 6 for a test device. Play services are up-to-date but this error still pops up. Anyone else having the same issue?

Comment: I have already updated GMS. This is not working.

Comment: late to the party, but I was having the same issue on a Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_arm64_v8a emulator, and fixed the issue by disabling Google Play Services. It doesn't seem to be possible to uninstall it or update its version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code from the manifest, check if you missed something in yours.

ManifestFile installLocation

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.******.***"
    android:installLocation="auto"
/>
<!-- make sure to add 'android:installLocation="auto"', it was missing for me -->
```

ManifestFile meta-data

```
<application
    <!-- ..... -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> <!--version--><!-- make sure added-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="barcode" /><!-- barcode,face,ocr make sure added-->
    <!-- ..... -->
</application>
```

- Check Internet connection
- Check storage for free space

If you work with an emulator

- Check if google service have are working properly
- Update it if need

Answer (score 1):

Try adding following in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
    ...

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="ocr"/>

</application>
```

Documentation can be found at https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/android

Answer (score -2):

For me, using other AVD fixed the problem.
The Google Play store should be up to date.
Try use emulator AVD - Android Nexus 5X.

[image: Android Studio AVD Manager with Google Play Store support]